# Is there a Michelson to Archetype (or other higher-level language) transcompiler/decompiler?

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson

Given an arbitrary smart contract address or Michelson code, [for example](https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1UcwQtaztLSq8oufdXAtWpRTfFySCj7gFM/code):

```
parameter (or
            (contract %push (big_map string
                                    (pair timestamp
                                          (pair timestamp
                                                (pair nat (pair nat (pair nat (pair nat nat))))))))
            (or (signature %revoke)
                (map %update string
                             (pair signature
                                   (pair timestamp
                                         (pair timestamp
                                               (pair nat (pair nat (pair nat (pair nat nat))))))))));
storage (pair
          (big_map %oracleData string
                               (pair timestamp
                                     (pair timestamp (pair nat (pair nat (pair nat (pair nat nat)))))))
          (option %publicKey key));
view "getPrice" string
      (pair timestamp (pair timestamp (pair nat (pair nat (pair nat (pair nat nat))))))
      { UNPAIR ;
        SWAP ;
        DUP ;
        DUG 2 ;
        CAR ;
        SWAP ;
        DUP ;
        DUG 2 ;
        MEM ;
        IF {} { PUSH string "bad request" ; FAILWITH } ;
        SWAP ;
        CAR ;
        SWAP ;
        GET ;
        IF_NONE { PUSH int 163 ; FAILWITH } {} };
code { UNPAIR ;
       IF_LEFT
         { NIL operation ; SWAP ; PUSH mutez 0 ; DUP 4 ; CAR ; TRANSFER_TOKENS ; CONS }
         { IF_LEFT
             { NONE key ;
               PACK ;
               SWAP ;
               DUP 3 ;
               CDR ;
               IF_NONE { PUSH int 117 ; FAILWITH } {} ;
               CHECK_SIGNATURE ;
               IF
                 {}
                 { PUSH string "WrongCondition: sp.check_signature(self.data.publicKey.open_some(), params, sp.pack(sp.set_type_expr(sp.none, sp.TOption(sp.TKey))))" ;
                   FAILWITH } ;
               NONE key ;
               UPDATE 2 ;
               EMPTY_BIG_MAP string
                              (pair timestamp
                                    (pair timestamp (pair nat (pair nat (pair nat (pair nat nat)))))) ;
               UPDATE 1 }
             { SWAP ;
               DUP ;
               DUG 2 ;
               CDR ;
               IF_NONE { PUSH string "revoked" ; FAILWITH } { DROP } ;
               DUP ;
               ITER { DUP ;
                      GET 3 ;
                      SWAP ;
                      DUP ;
                      DUG 2 ;
                      GET 4 ;
                      DUP 5 ;
                      CAR ;
                      DUP 4 ;
                      CAR ;
                      MEM ;
                      IF
                        { DUP 5 ;
                          CAR ;
                          DUP 4 ;
                          CAR ;
                          GET ;
                          IF_NONE { PUSH int 85 ; FAILWITH } {} ;
                          CAR ;
                          SWAP ;
                          DUP ;
                          DUG 2 ;
                          CAR ;
                          COMPARE ;
                          GT ;
                          IF
                            { DUP ;
                              DUP 4 ;
                              CAR ;
                              PAIR ;
                              PACK ;
                              DIG 2 ;
                              DUP 6 ;
                              CDR ;
                              IF_NONE { PUSH int 117 ; FAILWITH } {} ;
                              CHECK_SIGNATURE ;
                              IF {} { PUSH string "bad sig" ; FAILWITH } ;
                              DIG 3 ;
                              DUP ;
                              CAR ;
                              DIG 2 ;
                              SOME ;
                              DIG 3 ;
                              CAR ;
                              UPDATE ;
                              UPDATE 1 ;
                              SWAP }
                            { DROP 3 } }
                        { DROP 3 } } ;
               DROP } ;
           NIL operation } ;
       PAIR }
```

**Is there an existing tool to create an Archetype, LIGO or SmartPy code which in turn compiles back to that exact Michelson code?**

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I have found so far is decompiler from Michelson (Dune) to Liquidity: https://liquidity-lang.org/edit/.

The Dune part I think is a fork of the real Tezos blockchain, I am not sure.
But it is okay for some POCs.

Cheers